# How can I make my buttons invisible for 3 sec?

Tags: java, android

i have checked this links: 1- [How to show a button after 5 seconds in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742781/how-to-show-a-button-after-5-seconds-in-android-studio)

2- [How make a button invisible for 1 or 2 second on another button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841203/how-make-a-button-invisible-for-1-or-2-second-on-another-button-click)

But i couldnt understand where should i this handler in my code. I tried but didnt worked. "While u r going to home heard a scream " after this text i want to make visible my buttons. İ hope i could express myself.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    final TypeWriter tw = (TypeWriter) findViewById(R.id.tv);

            tw.setText("");
            tw.SetCharacterDelay(120);
            tw.animatedText("While u r going to home heard a scream ")






    Button btn2 = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent c = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(c);
        }
    });



}


}
```

Comment: Do you want to invisible after 3 secs ?

Comment: Yes. I want to make invisible after 3 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);


    invisibleButton(b);

}

private void invisibleButton(final View view){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 1000 * 3);

  }
}
```

But Remember your `import` **`Handler`** should be-:

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

**EDIT**

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    visibleButton(b);



}

private void visibleButton(final View view){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 1000 * 3);

  }
}
```

Comment: Why i cant this. I just add my codes with your advice.

Comment: @Emre can you please clear me where you want to invisible your Button at the time of starting activity or on button click

Comment: İ have 3 buttons in activity2. İ want to make invisible them when activity start for 3 sec or more. And then (after 3 sec) they will  become visible.

Comment: Ok Wait I am updating my answer

Comment: Sorry for that was my typing mistake and i have slow internet speed so its takes lots of time to update. you just need to change your invisibleButton method

Comment: i updated my codes and tw.setText("");
                tw.SetCharacterDelay(120);
                tw.animatedText - btn2.setOnClickListener  give an error: "Cannot resolve symbol..."

Comment: see i have updated your answer you just need to check your inbox and need to accept edit and check that will work

Comment: Man ty it didnt give any error but app is same. If u want i cant send u folders or screenshots

Comment: Hahaha man you are making a mistake you are initializing same button two times

Comment: Can you please update your xml file to your question

Comment: My buttons becoming invisible after 3 secs. it should have become when activity start. its getting better :)

Comment: Dont worry i am also begineer

Comment: No. buttons should have become visible after 3 secs but becoming invisible when activity start

Comment: then what you want when they should become invisible

Comment: Sorry i wrote wrong.  
Buttons should have become visible after 3 secs but becoming invisible when activity start

Comment: Ok i get your point man you want that when your app appears you button should be invisible but it should be visible after 3 sec

Comment: Yes.Exactly this is what i want

Comment: Done you can check my updated answer what i have done that i have invisble your button at staring and visible after 3 sec

Comment: ı wish.   <<<   Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    invisibleButton(b)   >>  just this working not other buttons working

Comment: i did same for other buttons

Comment: can you please update your question as i edited my ans by tag Edit and please delete your own ans

Comment: I hate it. What is it?

Comment: for handler you can learn from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Okey i guees i did. This was my first experience on this site. I dont know well.

Comment: Happy Coding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
Button btn2 = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.button3);

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do something after 3 secs
    }
}, 3000);
```